# How do I align an image using CSS grid?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to build a section of a website using CSS grid. I am trying to have the list and picture stay contained in the same row and shrink/grow proportionally when the screen changes size. The Code is pasted below. Any help is greatly appreciated.

[image: Current Screenshot]

I'm wondering if the error lies within my grid template.

```css
.pm {
  display: inline-grid;
  max-width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
  grid-template-areas: "title title" "list picture" "options options" "paragraph paragraph";
  grid-template-rows: 10% 1fr 20% 10%;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  align-items: center;
}

.pm h2 {
  grid-area: title;
  text-align: center;
}

.pm .container ul {
  grid-area: list;
}

.pm .container img {
  grid-area: picture;
  max-width: 30%;
  border-radius: 0.25em;
}

.pm .options {
  grid-area: options;
}

.pm .paragraph {
  grid-area: paragraph;
}
```

```html
<div class="pm section">
  <h2>Preventative Maintenance:</h2>
  
  <div class="container">
    <ul>
      <li>Calibration of each piece of equipment as required.</li>
      <li>Inspect any switches, controls and/or electrical components.</li>
      <li>Inspect motor brushes and clean the motor fan vents.</li>
      <li>Inspect and tighten hardware.</li>
      <li>Inspect all belts cables and chains.</li>
      <li>Lube all moving components as required.</li>
    </ul>
    <img src="./style/images/circuit.avif">
  </div>
  
  <div class="options">
    <h3>Options:</h3>
    
    <ul>
      <li>Monthly</li>
      <li>Quarterly</li>
      <li>Semi-annual</li>
      <li>Annual</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  
  <div class="paragraph">
    <p>Any findings will be reported in the invoice, with an option to have any findings quoted for repair, separately.</p>
    
    <p>Any parts needed, per the repair quote, would be ordered and all repairs would be scheduled following arrival of the parts.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The image is not in the picture section because it is nested inside the container and the img tag per se is not a grid-item.

Below the working code

```css
.pm {
  display: inline-grid;
  max-width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
  grid-template-areas: "title title" "list picture" "options options" "paragraph paragraph";
  grid-template-rows: 10% 1fr 20% 10%;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  align-items: center;
}

.pm h2 {
  grid-area: title;
  text-align: center;
}

.pm .container ul {
  grid-area: list;
}

.pm .img-container {
  grid-area: picture;
  max-width: 30%;
  border-radius: 0.25em;
}

.pm .options {
  grid-area: options;
}

.pm .paragraph {
  grid-area: paragraph;
}
```

```
<div class="pm section">
  <h2>Preventative Maintenance:</h2>
  
  <div class="container">
    <ul>
      <li>Calibration of each piece of equipment as required.</li>
      <li>Inspect any switches, controls and/or electrical components.</li>
      <li>Inspect motor brushes and clean the motor fan vents.</li>
      <li>Inspect and tighten hardware.</li>
      <li>Inspect all belts cables and chains.</li>
      <li>Lube all moving components as required.</li>
    </ul>
    
  </div>
  
  <div class="img-container">
    <img src="./style/images/circuit.avif">
  </div>

  <div class="options">
    <h3>Options:</h3>
    
    <ul>
      <li>Monthly</li>
      <li>Quarterly</li>
      <li>Semi-annual</li>
      <li>Annual</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  
  <div class="paragraph">
    <p>Any findings will be reported in the invoice, with an option to have any findings quoted for repair, separately.</p>
    
    <p>Any parts needed, per the repair quote, would be ordered and all repairs would be scheduled following arrival of the parts.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```